# quarkus-junit5-mockito is deprecated - How to mock rest clients when unittesting a Quarkus application?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I'm using the latest version of quarkus (3.4 at this moment) and as usual I used the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

[mockito is deprecated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQvdL.png)

When I imported it I had this issue, it is deprecated from version 3.2 of Quarkus.

And now how to mock ?

I tried using mockito but in new versions of quarkus it is deprecated.
I hope I can mock it somehow without using something deprecated.

Comment: According to documentation `Use {@link io.quarkus.test.InjectMock} and {@link MockitoConfig} instead.`

Answer (score 4):

`quarkus-junit5-mockito` is *NOT* deprecated.

What is deprecated is the `io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectMock` annotation, nothing else.

The replacement is the `io.quarkus.test.InjectMock` annotation, together with `io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectMock` if you need the extra options.

Answer (score -2):

I found a way. I'm not using something deprecated.

[Mocking with QuarkusMock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfrmz.png)

My example:

```
 ExtensionsService customMock = new ExtensionsService() {
            @Override
            public JsonObject getForbiddenNumbers() {
                return new JsonObject("{\"forbiddenNumbers\":[5,7,23]}");
            }
        };
        QuarkusMock.installMockForType(customMock, ExtensionsService.class, RestClient.LITERAL);
```

In this example ExtensionsService is the rest client.

For more information:
[Quarkus documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive#mocking-with-quarkusmock)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).